# "include"-esque function for Perl

Tags: perl, function, include

I have a function that I would like to define in two different Perl scripts, but dislike having to edit both. Is there a way I can `include` it (like in PHP) from an external file?

FUNC FILE:

```
sub test {

}
```

FILE 1:

```
include func_file;
foo();
bar();
test();
```

FILE 2:

```
include func_file;
blah();
test();
```

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712016/how-do-i-include-functions-from-another-file-in-my-perl-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include functions from another file in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712016/how-do-i-include-functions-from-another-file-in-my-perl-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Func.pm:

```
package Func;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( test );

sub test {
}

1;
```

File1.pl:

```
use Func;

test();
```

Comment: Imported files must return a true value.

Comment: `use`/`require` is for modules, `do` otherwise. [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376006/what-is-the-difference-between-library-files-and-modules/6379109#6379109)

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question narrowly:

Yes, you can include a file by using the [require('filename')](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) function.

To answer the question generally:

Perl has a complete mechanism for defining and exporting functions through its package mechanism.  This is [described in perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html). You should really use this mechanism, as you can eventually package up the module into a CPAN module, and make it available for others, or simply easy to install on other systems yourself.