# Importing sub into perl module package

Tags: perl

Coming from Python and Java background this is confusing me a bit. I have the following files:

Constants.pm

Utils.pl

Main.pl

**Constants.pm** has global variables that I'd like to share with **Main.pl** and **Utils.pl**.

**Utils.pl** has helper subs that I'd like to share with **Constants.pm** and **Main.pl**

```
#################### Constants.pm
package Constants;
require "Utils.pl";
use Exporter;
our @ISA = 'Exporter';

my %config = parseConfigFile("File.properties");

our @EXPORT = qw($var1 $var2 $var3);
our ($var1, $var2, $var3);

$var1 = $config{var1};
$var2 = $config{var2};
$var3 = $config{var3};


#################### Utils.pl
package Utils;
use Constants;

sub parseConfigFile {};
sub someSub {};

#################### Main.pl
use Constants;
require "Utils.pl"

my $var = someSub($var1);
```

When I run **Main.pl** I'm getting someSub is undefined error

Please help, thanks!

EDIT: I haven't tried @ikegami's answer instead I just moved everything in Constants into Utils.pm and importing Utils by using 'use' in main.pl

Comment: `require "Utils.pl"` makes no sense. `Utils.pl` is not a module.

Comment: Re "When I run Main.pl I'm getting someSub is undefined error", No, you get a syntax error. (`syntax error at a.pl line 4, near "my "`)

Comment: second answer tells me I can use "require" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712016/how-do-i-include-functions-from-another-file-in-my-perl-script

Comment: `require` is for files with a `package`. `do` is for files without (which is a very bad practice). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924)

Comment: ok see the above update. I added "package Utils;" to Utils.pl but now I'm getting parseConfigFile is undefined at Constants.pm line 6

Comment: You never import from from Utils, though

Comment: (And why wouldn't you name the file `Utils.pm`?)

Comment: What do you mean never import from Utils? I changed it Utils.pm but still getting the same error.

Comment: `use` is `require` + `import`. You bypassed the `import`, and you didn't setup `Utils` to export in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The following explanation applies to the original version of the question. The solution is the same.]

`require` only executes a file once, but you expect the identical subs to be present in two packages. The simple solution is to use `do` instead of `require`. But then you end up with a poor design. You end up with multiple instances of the variables and subs created by `Utils.pl`. It's much better to convert `Utils.pl` into a proper module (like `Constants.pm`).

`Constants.pm`:

```
package Constants;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Utils    qw( parseConfigFile );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $var1 $var2 $var3 );

my %config = parseConfigFile("File.properties");
our $var1 = $config{var1};
our $var2 = $config{var2};
our $var3 = $config{var3};

1;
```

`Utils.pm`:

```
package Utils;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Constants qw( ... );
use Exporter  qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( parseConfigFile someSub );

sub parseConfigFile { ... }
sub someSub { ... }

1;
```

`main.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Constants qw( $var1 );
use Utils     qw( someSub );

my $var = someSub($var1);
```

But oops! Constants uses Utils, and Utils uses Constants, and they both import from the other. That's a problem. You can [work around it](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639), but there's no reason for `parseConfigFile` to be in `Utils`, so let's just avoid the problem entirely.

`Constants.pm`:

```
package Constants;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $var1 $var2 $var3 );

sub parseConfigFile { ... }

my %config = parseConfigFile("File.properties");
our $var1 = $config{var1};
our $var2 = $config{var2};
our $var3 = $config{var3};

1;
```

`Utils.pm`:

```
package Utils;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Constants qw( ... );
use Exporter  qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( someSub );

sub someSub { ... }

1;
```

(I use `@EXPORT_OK` instead of `@EXPORT` because I believe it's a good idea to explicitly name your imports.)

Comment: How does `do` help?  The subs would still get defined in the wrong package.

Comment: @mob, Instead of being compiled into main *or* Constants, using `do` instead of `require` would have them compiled into both main *and* Constants. (Hum, the OP seems to have added `package Utils;`, completely negating my explanation.)

Comment: @ikegami instead of separating into Constants and Utils and I just moved variables and subs into 'Utils.pm' and importing Utils by using 'use' in main.pl