# Perl - get abs path to module from other directory in main script

Tags: perl, module, getcwd

I created a simple perl script which is splited into 2 files - `main.pl` and `content.pm` 
The main script is placed in `Project` directory and `content.pm` (module) is placed in `Project/utils` directory. Now I want to use `content.pm` in `main.pl` I made something like this to use this module:

```
use Cwd;
use lib Cwd::abs_path(getcwd()."/utils");
use utils::content;
```

but if I do it this way, I get an error:

```
Cant locate utils/content.pm in 
@INC (you may need to install the utils::content module) 
@INC contains: /Perl/utils /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 ...) 
at ./main.pl line 10.
```

Is it possible to run this main.pl script using content.pm with no errors? Maybe I should not use `getcwd()` (I think it use a working directory instead of abs_path, but I'm not sure)?

Comment: Have a look at _[How do I use a Perl module from a relative location?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/787899/5830574)_ and the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, `getcwd` is from where you run the script, not where the script is located.

Comment: Ok, it looks good :). Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `FindBin`.

Specifically:

```
use FindBin qw( );
use lib $FindBin::RealBin."/utils"; 
use content;
```

Comment: Note: This assumes the OP used `package content;` instead of `package utils::content;` in `content.pm`.

Comment: I have `package content` in the content.pm